# Upper field on constraint Odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to upper a field before insert a record on database in Odoo 10.

I tried this and works well:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('field')
    def to_upper(self):
        if self.field == "x":
            self.field = self.field.upper()
```

But if I add an else like

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('field')
    def to_upper(self):
        if self.field == "x":
            self.field = self.field.upper()
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Error")
```

Always return else's ValidationError (while if statement being true, because without else works well)

Anybody can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## constrain must not be used to manipulate value.

> Each time you try to set value of "field" it will trigger constrain 
>   itself and this will leads to "RECURSION"!!
>
> here you are always end up with raise ValidationError("Error") because of recursion.
>
> ==>here what happening is first when you are converting value of "field" from 'x' to 'X' and setting it again to field doing this calls constrain again with value 'X' and your condition becomes False and raises Error.

put print statement in if & else and check console you will get better idea!

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can u give me an example on how to log it? Im pretty new with odoo and python :( Thanks!! Or idea on how can I manipulate data before insert?

Comment: you are running develop environment then in local server then you can check by simple python Print statement and that will be print along with logs on terminal/console where you started odoo server. AND To manipulate value you can use on_change or create/write methods (check out docs> https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html)

Comment: Thanks! Just added create/write methods and works well. But I've a problem. On write, if I edit value of one field, it requires to change values of all fields which I declared on write override. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Okay, I fix it checking if key exists in values on def write(self, values). Thanks your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you

```
    @api.constrains('name')
    def _check_name(self):     
        if self.name:
            final_name=''
            for letters in self.name:
                if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\- .]',letters):
                    final_name += letters
                else:
                    not_accept_letters = letters
                    raise ValidationError(_('The character that you entered has not accepted %s')% not_accept_letters) 
            if self.name.islower():
                self.name = final_name.upper()
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!